# Help, i accidentally used a dirty measuring cup

Tags: food-safety

I accidentally used a dirty measuring cup that was in sink to fill my pot to make mac n cheese, I thought I washed it good but after eating I seen sediment at the bottom of it, the water boiled for 14minutes, should I be worried?

Comment: Sorry, "should I be worried" is an opinion-based question. The only thing we can judge is safe/not safe, as defined by regulations - and I think you are already aware that regulations require using clean utensils. From there on, it is impossible to calculate any kind of objective risk amount.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you previously used your measuring cup for toxic substances, or perhaps it contained rotten or mouldy food, and then failed to clean it, you should not worry.